# How to update yarn.lock in automatic synk.io PR's?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, synk.io

Snyk.io is very helpful in that it will update the `package.json`'s in my yarn monorepo.

However, I've not been able to figure out how to actually perform the `yarn install` through the Synk UI.

I've tried reading through their documentation, but there's no clear way to enable Synk to run the `yarn install` needed to generate the new `package.json`.

Maybe I need to set up my own Github action to perform this update and commit the change only on Synk PRs?